# Repeat div till center responsive

Tags: html, css, background, center, repeat

I would like to find out how can i repeat div till | centered div | and repeat div again (like a table). As i understand, i have to use responsive condition, but i have no idea how can i use it.

here is my code sample (HTML):

```
<!-- Slider -->
<div id="slider">
  <div class="big"><img class="opt" src="images/urban1.jpg" width="930" height="367" alt="big_thumb"></div>

  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="line"></div>
      <div id="thumbs">
        <div id="button_left"></div>
      </div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider #wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 87px;
    border: 1px #666 solid;
}

#slider #wrap .line {
    background:url(../images/dotted_line.png) top repeat-x;
    width: ??;
    height: 15px;
    float: left;    
}

#slider #wrap #thumbs {
    width: 940px;
    height: 87px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you further explain what you're trying to accomplish? I don't fully understand.

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gB6ew/

Comment: I am trying to repeat div from corner to center and then repeat again, but for instance if i set width in pixels it doesn't repeat to center if i am looking through larger display. It's hard to explain this situation properly.

Comment: so what about showing pictures?

Comment: It's about properly repeating div from corner to center... and repeat again

Comment: Can you replicate the desired result in an image? Your question is as clear as mud.